# While debugging I get this when using Watch: Internal error in the C# compiler

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've been working along very happily in an app in VS2017.  Debugging just fine. Then, all of a sudden...

When I am debugging and try to hover over a variable, I don't get the normal popup with details of the object.  And if I put it in the Watch, I get this for the value:

> Internal error in the C# compiler

I closed and re-opened VS, then I rebooted.  Still get the same error.

There is very little about this out there. Has anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8813526a-8ff8-496c-bca2-f8c9b54b9fa5/internal-error-in-the-c-compiler-viewing-instances-when-debugging-a-dump-of-w3wpexe?forum=vsdebug) that worked:

> Please view menu Tools-> Options > debugging > enable Use Managed
>   Compatibility Mode, and then debug your dump file, how about the
>   result?

No clue why it was working and then suddenly stopped.  But, it's working again now.

**Edit LONG After:**

This recently got an upvote, so the problem is still out there, lurking. I should add that after this solution solved the problem, it soon came back and nothing I could try got rid of it. I ended up totally removing all traces of VS and re-installing it, which pretty much took all day.

**Edit LONG LONG After:**

Even after uninstalling and re-installing VS, the problem eventually came back. This time I took my laptop to my employer's helpdesk team and they ended up just giving me a new laptop.

If that's isn't an option for you, may God help you, because I have no idea.  I found some threads about this on various MS forums, and the MS employees always just close them with "not able to reproduce".

Comment: I tired this and I am still getting the Internal error.

Comment: @RyanWilson, did you get this resolved?  See the edit I just made to my answer.

Comment: I believe I ended up re-installing software. I moved to a different laptop at my work so ever since migrating to the new laptop I haven't experienced this issue.

Comment: I just received this curse.  Cleaning the solution, removing the .vs directory, rebooting, and rebuilding did not fix the problem.  At the same time, I found that I could not step into the code in a DLL where I could step yesterday.  I have Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, Version 15.7.2, running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this was due to dynamic assembly loading.

The issue would only appear after the debugger stepped over a call to the `Assembly.LoadFrom(...)` method that tried to load an assembly with the same name as an assembly in the assembly loader context.

I fixed the issue by checking if the assembly that was about to be loaded was already in the assembly loader context. If it was, the assembly would be skipped.

Rough code of my solution:

```cs
// Load the assembly to the reflection context to check for any conflicts in the assembly load context
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
AssemblyName assemblyName = assembly .GetName();

List<AssemblyName> existingAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .Select(assembly => assembly.GetName())
    .Where(x => x.Name == assemblyName.Name && x.Version.ToString() != assemblyName.Version.ToString())
    .ToList();

if (existingAssemblies.Any())
{
    // Skip the assembly if there are already assemblies with the same name but a different version
    return;
}
else
{
    // Load the assembly into the assembly loader context
    assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
}
```

References:

[Strange behavior when loading assemblies and its dependencies programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738633/strange-behavior-when-loading-assemblies-and-its-dependencies-programatically)

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/10859

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19257

Comment: Thanks very much! This solution solved my problem, i confirmed that one assembly was loaded twice, as to cause the watch windows to report "Internal error in the c# compiler". Visual Studio should deal with this situation with a more explicity warning.

Answer (score 1):

I also run into this problem right after the following code:

```
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assembly, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
```

Eventually I understood that it's happened only when passing the executing assembly (which received by calling to Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).
I assuming that the compiler don't know how to debug the executing assembly in such case (maybe because it's cause to a conflict between those assemblies).

**Soluting**:
Don't use executing assembly

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue using VS2022 and was not willing to uninstall it. I tried restarting VS to no avail.

I solved my issue by deleting all temporary files in my repo using the following git command (at the root of the repo):

```
git clean -fdx
```

This command resets the repo to its unmodified state keeping modified files (unstaged modifications will be lost, you've been warned!)

You could also probably simply delete .vs/ folder and all temporary bin/ and obj/ folders but I found it simpler to use git command (TFVC users will have to do the cleanup manually!).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well.

It turns out that I had two using statements that defined a type from a specific namespace.

```
using Type = namespaces.Type;

namespace namespaces
{
   using Type = otherNamespace.Type;
   ...
}
```

It's probably a rare occurrence in the world outside my company, but if you're running into this error, it's something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this with a web project in VS2022, rolled back to VS2019, turned on Managed Compatibility Mode, still had the error. Turned out it was just my smelly code.

```
var assembly = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var appDomain = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain();
var assemblyBuilder = appDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assembly, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
```

I had this in a startup routine. Once the debugger hit that third line of code I start getting the error. I can inspect variables right up to that line.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an extension that I had recently enabled.  Disabling and restarting it did the trick.